# Can I retrieve a spreadsheet with just a title name for google sheets api v4 .net?

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I know that there is a way to get a spreadsheet using a sheetID. I was wondering if it's possible to get a sheet using a spreadsheet's title rather than sheetID without using a map. I know that it's possible to retrieve a sheet using its name in a spreadsheet using linq. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I meant to say if there is a way to get a spreadsheet using its title.

Comment: Not with the Sheets API - with Drive, yes